# Understanding one line for loop dictionary to panda in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-2.x

I have read several of the StackOverflow topics on this as well as Google.  This is not my code.  It was written for Python2.  I am trying to understand a line that gives and error in Python 3.  I am having difficulty wrapping my head around this one line for loop.

```
para['row_colors'] = pd.DataFrame([dict({'index': row}.items() + row_colors[row].items()) for row in table.index]).set_index('index')'
```

'row' is a sample name being used as a key.  I get that.
That '+' is throwing the error.  Can't do a dict.item + dict.item.  I don't understand the structure of the dictionary being built.

Comment: could you please share the link where you got it from? or what is the error message when you run in python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because `dict.items()` no longer returns a list in Python 3, rather, it returns a special object that acts as a set-like *view* over the items in the dictionary (same with `.keys` and `.values`). The simplest fix is simply to do `list(dict.items())`.

However, in this particular case, `dict({'index': row}.items() + row_colors[row].items())` should probably just be `{'index':row, **row_colors[row]}` in python 3.

So you could use:

```
para['row_colors'] = pd.DataFrame([{'index': row, **row_colors[row]} for row in table.index]).set_index('index')'
```

to use more modern syntax.

To understand what the previous version was doing, note that the `dict` constructor accepts an iterable of key-value pairs:

```
>>> dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Since `.items()` used to return a list of key-value pairs, you could do something like

```
dict(d1.items() + d2.items())
```

To merge two dicts. To transliterate this into Python 3, you would need something like:

```
>>> d1 = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'zing'}
>>> d2 = {"apple": 42}
>>> dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'zing', 'apple': 42}
```

But python 3 has even more convenient syntax, you can just do:

```
>>> {**d1, **d2}
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'zing', 'apple': 42}
```

Or, using specific key-value pairs more flexibly:

```
>>> {'index': 'column1', **d1, 'frob': 'bob', **d2}
{'index': 'column1', 'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'zing', 'frob': 'bob', 'apple': 42}
```

Finally, note that Python 3.9 [will be adding the `|` operator as a merge operator for dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html#dictionary-merge-update-operators), allowing the very terse:

```
>>> d1 | d2
{'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'zing', 'apple': 42}
```

For the simplest case

Comment: Note that a decent Python editor / IDE would give a warning that explains the problem. For example, PyCharm warns: "Class 'ItemsView' does not define '__add__', so the + operator can not be used on its instances." The solution given here is the correct fix to that problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I follow you.  This one liner was building key:value pairs using two lists.  Python 2 returned a list for dict.items() and list+list is valid.  I see the ** syntax now.  I will toy with this some more and see if I can make it work on my own.  I am accepting what you wrote as the answer.